# How to solve an OverflowError when exporting pandas dataframe to JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, jupyter

In Jupyter, I have a dataframe of 400 000 objects that I can't entirely export to a JSON file without facing the following error.

The export is working great as long as I limit the exportation to the first 141 000 objects , whatever the order of these first objects.

Should I be aware of any size limitation dealing with large JSON files ?
Thank you.

```
OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-254-b59373f1eeb2> in <module>
----> 1 df4.to_json('test.json', orient = 'records')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in to_json(self, path_or_buf, orient, date_format, double_precision, force_ascii, date_unit, default_handler, lines, compression, index)
   1889                             default_handler=default_handler,
   1890                             lines=lines, compression=compression,
-> 1891                             index=index)
   1892 
   1893     def to_hdf(self, path_or_buf, key, **kwargs):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json/json.py in to_json(path_or_buf, obj, orient, date_format, double_precision, force_ascii, date_unit, default_handler, lines, compression, index)
     56         double_precision=double_precision, ensure_ascii=force_ascii,
     57         date_unit=date_unit, default_handler=default_handler,
---> 58         index=index).write()
     59 
     60     if lines:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json/json.py in write(self)
     99         return self._write(self.obj, self.orient, self.double_precision,
    100                            self.ensure_ascii, self.date_unit,
--> 101                            self.date_format == 'iso', self.default_handler)
    102 
    103     def _write(self, obj, orient, double_precision, ensure_ascii,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json/json.py in _write(self, obj, orient, double_precision, ensure_ascii, date_unit, iso_dates, default_handler)
    154                                                double_precision,
    155                                                ensure_ascii, date_unit,
--> 156                                                iso_dates, default_handler)
    157 
    158 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json/json.py in _write(self, obj, orient, double_precision, ensure_ascii, date_unit, iso_dates, default_handler)
    110             date_unit=date_unit,
    111             iso_dates=iso_dates,
--> 112             default_handler=default_handler
    113         )
    114 

OverflowError: int too big to convert
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no inherent limitation on data size in JSON, so this isn't your problem: the message suggests some difficulty with a particular integer value.

This underlines the difficulty of working with such large files, since you now have to isolate the particular record that's causing the problems in the middle of the `to_json` call.

Since you know roughly where the problem is you could try converting subsets of your data frame in a bisection technique to home in on the row that's causing the issues.

Answer (score 4):

Try the below code:

```py
df4.to_json('test.json', orient='records', default_handler=str)
```

`default_handler` is used if object cannot otherwise be converted to a suitable format in JSON.

Read [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error when one cell (or column) of my DataFrame was a `Pathlib.Path` object instead of a string.

When the DataFrame is printed to console, the output doesn't show anything suspicious. This can make this error particularly hard to debug.

#### Reproducing the error

```py
# Imports
import sys
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

# Show versions
print(sys.version_info)
# sys.version_info(major=3, minor=11, micro=6, releaselevel='final', serial=0)

print(pd.__version__)
# '2.2.0'

# Generate DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(
  [
    {
      "a": Path("/home"),
      "b": "/mnt"
    },
    {
      "a": "/home2",
      "b": "/mnt2"
    }
  ]
)

# Print dataframe
# Everything looks as expected
print(df)

#         a      b
# 0   /home   /mnt
# 1  /home2  /mnt2

# Try and generated a json string
# This will fail
print(df.to_json(orient='records'))
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alexiswl/.config/JetBrains/RemoteDev-PY/_media_UMCCR_PycharmProjects_orcabus/scratches/scratch_12.py", line 37, in <module>
    df.to_json(orient='records')
  File "/home/alexiswl/mambaforge/envs/python3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 333, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/alexiswl/mambaforge/envs/python3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2699, in to_json
    return json.to_json(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/alexiswl/mambaforge/envs/python3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py", line 210, in to_json
    ).write()
      ^^^^^^^
  File "/home/alexiswl/mambaforge/envs/python3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py", line 263, in write
    return ujson_dumps(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
OverflowError: Maximum recursion level reached
```

### Debugging help

Instead you can print to dict and this might give you an idea as to what cells in your DataFrame are not JSON serializable.

```
print(df.to_dict(orient='records'))
# [{'a': PosixPath('/home'), 'b': '/mnt'}, {'a': '/home2', 'b': '/mnt2'}]
```